# Adding Eclipse Mylyn Subtasks disabled

Tags: eclipse, task, mylyn

I've taken the plunge and am using Mylyn finally, and I don't know why I didn't do this sooner, it's amazing.  That said there are a few features I haven't been able to get working, one specifically is "Sub-tasks".

When I `right click existing task -> new -> subtask`, the subtask option is greyed out.

We're using Bitbucket as our git repo.  I've seen in other mylyn screenshots additional options that are not in my local copy, so I'm beginning to suspect that certain options are only available on certain platforms.

**Are mylyn subtasks repo depenedent, or is there another reason that would prevent me from being able to use sub-tasks?**

Comment: which Mylyn version are you using ?

Comment: @flafoux Mylyn v3.14.2 with the v1.1.0 Bitbucket connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from bitbucket, it doesn't handle subtask, see [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/6043/subtasks-for-issues-bb-7249)

Comment: Was afraid of that. Thanks for the link.